# Get the percent amount of time left with only the end date and current date

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two variables: `endDate = new DateTime(2013, 10, 24, 17, 30, 35)` and `currentDate = DateTime.Now`. The amount of time remaining is `endDate - currentDate`. How do I turn that into a percentage?

**Edit**: I see, was wondering if there was some sort of crazy math magic that could happen with just these two numbers but I guess it is impossible without the start date.

Comment: A percentage of what? A percentage is a proportion - presumably you're interested in the proportion of time remaining compared to some "original" amount of time... without the original amount of time, there's nothing for it to be a percentage of.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a `startDate` as well? Just perform basic math..

Comment: You would need a start date to be able to calculate how much time is left, otherwise you're just counting down from `DateTime.Now` to `endDate`.

Comment: "Crazy magic math" isn't going to get around a lack of information. Forget computers for now: if I gave you "10th June 2012" as a current date, and "13th August 2014" as an end date, what would the result be and why? If you can't answer that, then neither can a computer however smart the program is.

Comment: You're missing the denominator for your percentage calculation.  You need to have another variable for the total time, or the start date so that you can calculate the total time.

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

```
endDate - currentDate = 100% The amount of time remaining!!
```

***Or*** if you modify your code so that:

```
 endDate = new DateTime(2013, 10, 24, 17, 30, 35)
```

and

```
 startDate = DateTime.Now()
```

The amount of time remaining is endDate - DateTime.Now()

Then you can turn that into a percentage.

```
    amountLeftDate= endDate - DateTime.Now()

    if (!(s >= DateTime.Now()) && amountLeftDate > 0) {
        percentoftimeleft = (amountLeftDate) * 100 / (endDate  - startDate);
    }
```

and everytime you run

Answer (score 0):

You can't because you would need to know the starting date.